# Namespace 'Intl' has no exported member 'LocalesArgument'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using React and TypeScript I'm trying to type a function that passes arguments to `Date.toLocaleString` but when I try to use `Intl.LocalesArgument` I get an error saying `Namespace 'Intl' has no exported member 'LocalesArgument'`. My `tsconfig.json` is below and I have tried changing `target` to `es2020` and restarting the dev server to no avail.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was on TypeScript `4.6.3`, upgrading to the latest version (`4.8.2` at the time of writing) fixed this issue.

Answer (score 3):

In case you cannot update the version, this can be solved by going to your tsconfig and adding "ES2020.Intl" to your "Lib" array:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "lib": [<other libs>, "ES2020.Intl"]
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this on an older TS version and fixed it by adding `index.d.ts` under `types` dir with this in it:

```
declare namespace Intl {
  type LocalesArgument =
    | UnicodeBCP47LocaleIdentifier
    | Locale
    | readonly (UnicodeBCP47LocaleIdentifier | Locale)[]
    | undefined
}
```

And then adding `./types` to the `compilerOptions.types` array in `tsconfig`.